# How do I create a Ctrl+z event on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, undo

I am trying to make an 'undo' action like Ctrl + Z.
But I really don't know how to make it.

This is my code. I want to add a `ctrl+z event`, but I don't know what to do.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const modeBtn = document.querySelector("#mode-btn");

const CANVAS_WIDTH = 800;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 800;

canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
ctx.lineCap = "round";

let isPainting = false;
let isFilling = false;

function onMove(event) {
  if (isPainting) {
    ctx.lineTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
    ctx.stroke();
    return;
  }
  ctx.moveTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
}

function startPainting() {
  isPainting = true;
}

function cancelPainting() {
  isPainting = false;
  ctx.beginPath();
}

function onModeClick() {
  if (isFilling) {
    isFilling = false;
  } else {
    isFilling = true;
  }
}

function onCanvasClick() {
  if (isFilling) {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
  }
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMove);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPainting);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", cancelPainting);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", cancelPainting);
canvas.addEventListener("click", onCanvasClick);

modeBtn.addEventListener("click", onModeClick);
```

```
<canvas></canvas>
    <div class="btns">
      <button id="mode-btn">Draw</button>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
```

I used split(-1,1), but it didn't work at all, or it was deleted completely, not undo.

I am a beginner. I don't know how to apply it. Help me, please.

Comment: It sounds like you will need to store the state of your canvas each time the user modifies it (or at least all the actions the user has performed), so that you can replay/unplay it whenever you want to.

Comment: You've either to record all you draw, or save a snapshot of every modified drawing. When CTRL + Z is pressed, you've to restore a saved snapshot, or redraw the canvas using the record.

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner, the simplest approach you can take is to keep an array of the positions that you drew on in a stack, and during the undo operation, just pop those values and clear those positions on the canvas.

To listen for the `ctrl+z` keypress you can use something like this -

```js
      function onUndo() {
        var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;
        if (evtobj.keyCode == 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey) undo();
      }
      document.addEventListener("keydown", onUndo);
```

And to undo the operations, the simplest code could look something like this (note this basically the opposite of what you were doing during drawing) -

```js
      function undo() {
        const color = ctx.strokeStyle;
        ctx.strokeStyle = BG_COLOR;

        if (actions.length === 0) {
          ctx.strokeStyle = color;
          return;
        }
        const action = actions.pop();
        if (action.type === "move") {
          ctx.lineTo(action.x, action.y);
          ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      }
```

Here `BG_COLOR` is background color of your canvas

Also, this approach might work for now, but it would get difficult to manage and maintain as you add more kinds of drawing approaches to your canvas. To do this in a more maintainable way, I would suggest that you look into the [memento pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/memento)